# How to convert rows of same name(STATE) to columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, reformatting

I am playing around with the us_rent_income data from tidyverse and I cannot figure how to convert the rows into columns

```
GEOID NAME variable estimate 
 
01    Alabama  income  24476
02    Alaska   income   32940
02    Alaska   variable  1200
04    Arizona  variable   27517
04    Arizona  variable   972
```

I would like to convert the variable column,
into two different columns 'income' and 'variable',
and convert the estimate value as the respective income and rent value as such:

```
GEOID   NAME     income   rent  
01      Alabama  24476    747
02      Alaska   32940    1200
04      Arizona  27517    972
```

I attempted to do

```
reshape(us_rent_income, idvar=c("NAME","GEOID"), timevar="variable", direction="wide")
```

but the data outputs with all NA